# How to Fetch the Urdu language Words from plist?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, escaping, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I have a plist which contain urdu language Words and also have English language words.as below screenshot

[image]

Now my Code is to fetch data is given Below

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[words removeAllObjects];
[means removeAllObjects];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"urdutoeng" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
 for (int i=0; i<[array2 count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary* dict =  [array2 objectAtIndex:i];
        [words addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"Urdu"]];
    [means addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"English"]];
    [Types addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"Nature"]];
    }
  }
```

This part of code work fine for me as my below screen shot[image][image]

Now problem is when i search any words through searchbar it return Empty result beacuse my search array contain words in Different Formate my code for search array is

```
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *countriesToLiveInDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:words forKey:@"Countries"];
[listOfItems addObject:countriesToLiveInDict];
copyListOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

My Searchbar code is

```
#pragma mark Content Filtering
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
 {
[copyListOfItems removeAllObjects];
 NSLog(@"listOfItemsdata :%@",listOfItems);
for (NSString *cellLabel in [[listOfItems objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Countries"])
{
    NSComparisonResult result = [cellLabel compare:searchText options: (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        [copyListOfItems addObject:cellLabel];
    }
}
  }

#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
 - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller  shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
NSLog(@"searchstring :%@",searchString);
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];
return YES;
}
```

When i Nslog the listOfItems Array it show text some thing like

NSLog(@"listOfItemsdata :%@",listOfItems);

listOfItemsdata :(
        {
        Countries =         (
            " \U0627\U0628",
            " \U0627\U0628 \U0628\U06be\U06cc",
            " \U0627\U0628 \U062a\U0628",
            " \U0627\U0628 \U062a\U06a9",
            " \U0627\U0628 \U062c\U0628 \U06a9\U06c1",
            " \U0627\U0628 \U0633\U06d2",
Its show that my data goes in some other formate thats why searchbar is unable to search it.
Any help or Suggestion will be appriated.Thanks

Comment: NSLog() prints an escape sequence "\Unnnn" for many Unicode characters, the array itself contains the correct characters. - Can you show the NSLog() output of a search string that is not found?

Comment: oky thanks let me nslog it

Comment: - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    NSLog(@"searchstring :%@",searchString);
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];
    return YES;
}                                                               nslog result searchstring :ل

Comment: And where in your array should this string be found?

Comment: i want to  search string is equal to some of the strings in the array.

Comment: And does your array contain the string `ل` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23336/discussion-between-martin-r-and-nsstack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Urdu entries in the plist have a space as first character. This is the reason that searching always produced an empty list.

As a workaround, one can remove leading and trailing spaces from the entries before comparing:

```
for (NSString *cellLabel in [[listOfItems objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Countries"])
{
    NSString *trimmed = [cellLabel stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSComparisonResult result = [trimmed compare:searchText options: (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        [copyListOfItems addObject:cellLabel];
    }
}
```